# Representatives for $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]/\pi$ of bounded absolute value

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

For $\pi$ a prime element of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]$, can one always find a complete set of representatives $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{N\pi}$ for the residue field $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]/\pi\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]$ such that $|\alpha_j|<|\pi|$ for all $j$? Is there a lowest such bound on the absolute values?

Comment: $\mathbb Z[i]$ is an euclidean domain, so the answer is yes.

Comment: More precisely, $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a euclidean domain w.r.t. the complex absolute value.